# Color coded Sharepoint Enterprise Wiki templates?

Tags: sharepoint, wiki, code-snippets, color-coding

The company I work for (web development) wants to start using a Sharepoint Enterprise Wiki for sharing, amongst other things, best practises and code snippets. To make it readable and more user friendly, we would like the code snippets/ code examples, to be color coded, like they are in Visual Studio. My questions to you smart people are:

1. Do you know about any Sharepoint Enterprise Wiki-templates that allow color coding code snippets?
2. If not do you have any good advice on how to enable color coding in a Sharepoint Wiki page?  Is there a good plugin to use? Perhaps a web part.
3. If getting Sharepoint color coding for code snippets is to difficult, can you recommend some good website that helps color code code snippets?

Any advice you might have would be highly appreciated. I have tried to find information on Google, but has not found a good solution yet.